# How to set keyListener for edittext in Android?

Tags: android-edittext, keylistener

I want to input a Hexadecimal number in a EditText. How to set keyListener in order to limit the input value?

Thank you!

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) text watcher or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10649139/4790490) post.

Comment: @Hearty Could you provide me some demo codes, I still don't know how to use text watcher well…

Comment: I guess @P. Rai's answer may help you. Further more i suggest you to do validation logic on `afterTextChanged (Editable s){ }` event using **regex** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:inputType="number"` in your EditText xml

You can also add text watcher `editText.addTextChangedListener (new MyTextWatcher ());`

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I want to input a Hexadecimal number in a EditText.  Using android:inputType="number" in your EditText xml, I can't input letters.(abcde / ABCDE)