# How to define which values could be written in EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, hex

I need to write hexadecimal values in EditText (for example 0x1F, so I need to write numbers from range 0-9 and characters a-f and x. I found some solutions to set range but only for numbers. What about the characters?
From the other hand, is there any way to "disable" unnecessary values from keyboard view?

UPDATE:
I just found easiest solution for me. To EditText properties i added:

```
android:digits="0123456789ABCDEFX"
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648449/how-do-i-set-a-edittext-to-the-input-of-only-hexadecimal-numbers

Comment: Found solution also there, but updated question and added just found easiest solution for me. Thanks.